# "reboot and select proper boot device" with healthy disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

So I understand it's basically a very noob and quite often question on the forums, that's why it's even harder to search some relevant answer in case one understands a little bit more about the problem. But... I have some concerns and maybe you could either confirm them or point me to some thing that did not come to my mind.

So, I have 2 laptops: personal and company. I haven't been using personal for a while and when I turned it on this famous message appeared. First thing which came to my mind was problem is related to the disk. So I tried to swap these SSDs from both laptops and SSDs came out not corrupted, they're perfectly healthy. Disk from personal laptop boots in the company one and disk from company laptop does not boot in personal laptop as well. So problem is not related to disks. Both SSDs have Linux on them and both boot in the healthy laptop.
So it the problem in the motherboard? BIOS (or the UEFI)? I did not touch the BIOS for several years, everything just worked. I tried changing modes: legacy and uefi, then disabled secure boot, basically tried every combination, played with resetting the BIOS and taking out CMOS battery, but the message does not change. Then I tried to update/flash the BIOS and again - message is the same.

My concern and idea is motherboard needs to be fixed. What do you think?

P.S: maybe context would be helpful. It's MSI GE62 6QE, the original SSD (which tends to be healthy) is Samsung 970 EVO, BIOS version is 2.17.1255.

Comment: A repair-shop will know better.

Comment: @harrymc That is what came to my mind after all tryings and experiments and just wanted to hear some similar thoughts here before getting it into repair.  Thank you!